# Start PHP function / script on link click

Tags: php

I'm making a forum and now I'm trying to make a button that gives a user a top(like) when its pressed.

I'm trying to start a PHP / MySQL function or script when the like link gets pressed.
But I'm using an iFrame to load the page in, so I can't use /page.php?like=1 or something. So I got this PHP Function to load in forum comments.

```
function foraTopicComments($x)
{   
    global $con;

    $d = $con->query("SELECT * FROM forum_comments WHERE id_topic = '$x' ORDER BY id DESC");

    $i = 0;


    if(mysqli_num_rows($d) > 0){

        while($r = $d->fetch_object()){
            $writer = $r->writer;

            $ui = $con->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$writer'");
            $u = $ui->fetch_object();                   

            $date = $r->date;

            echo '<div class="row fora">';
            echo '<div class="box" type="grey">';
            echo '<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-5" style="padding: 10px; text-align: center;">
                    <b><u>' . $r->writer . '</u></b><br /><br />
                    <br />
                    <p>Posts: ' . $u->posts . '</p>
                    <p>Tops: ' . $u->respect . '</p>
                    <a href="&top=1"><i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                  </div>';                  
            echo '<div class="col-md-10 col-sm-9 col-xs-7" style="min-height: 327px;background-color: white;word-wrap: break-word;padding: 10px;">';
            echo '<div class="text fora">' . $r->comment . '</div>';
            echo '<div class="text fora signature"> ' . $u->mission . '</div>';
            echo '<div class="text fora date">'. $date .'</div>';
            echo '</div>';
            echo '</div>';
            echo '</div>';
        }


    }
}
```

So now when this gets clicked:

```
<a href="&top=1"><i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

I want to run an update statement in my code with the $writer variable as unique identifier.

Can someone help me out here? I'm kinda stuck and already tried a lot of methods..

Comment: You should try learning Ajax, it allows you to run functions withou refreshing your page, by sending data to the server via javascript.

Comment: I know, I tried this but I only need the onclick trigger for the link, I don't need to send any data with it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using AJAX and jquery to send likes to your PHP pages.

you can read on AJAX and JQuery here 
[W3School AJAX tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/)¸
[W3School JQuery tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/)

But basicly what you need is some a jquery script, a php script only for the like and that's it. 
I put some exemple down here but i havn't tested it.

JQuery :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.like').on('click', function(){
        $.ajax({
        'url': 'path/to/your/file.php',
        'method': 'GET',
         'data': {'id': idOfTheComment},
        'success': function(){
             console.log('success ! ');
         },
         'error': function(error){
             console.log('Error : ' + error)
         }
         });
     });
});
```

HTML

```
<div>
    <button class='like'></button>
</div>
```

PHP:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_GET['id']) {
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    // do your database connection and insert here.
}
```

Hope it helps !
- Nic

Answer (score 0):

## Approach without ajax ( I highly suggest Ajax)

Let's say your update  function is call `update.php`. When you click the link, you could call the update.php with some **GET** parameters (the $writer variable in your case). Then, the update.php process the page and redirect to your page. You could also use the same page to handle this. This approach is easy for a beginner but Ajax is better for user experience.

**Links generation**

```
function foraTopicComments($x)
{
    global $con;

    $d = $con->query("SELECT * FROM forum_comments WHERE id_topic = '$x' ORDER BY id DESC");

    $i = 0;


    if (mysqli_num_rows($d) > 0) {

        while ($r = $d->fetch_object()) {
            $writer = $r->writer;

            $ui = $con->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$writer'");
            $u = $ui->fetch_object();

            $date = $r->date;

            echo '<div class="row fora">';
            echo '<div class="box" type="grey">';
            echo '<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-5" style="padding: 10px; text-align: center;">
                        <b><u>' . $r->writer . '</u></b><br /><br />
                        <br />
                        <p>Posts: ' . $u->posts . '</p>
                        <p>Tops: ' . $u->respect . '</p>
                        <a href="&top=1" onclick="./update.php?Writer=' . $r->writer . '"><i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                      </div>';
            echo '<div class="col-md-10 col-sm-9 col-xs-7" style="min-height: 327px;background-color: white;word-wrap: break-word;padding: 10px;">';
            echo '<div class="text fora">' . $r->comment . '</div>';
            echo '<div class="text fora signature"> ' . $u->mission . '</div>';
            echo '<div class="text fora date">' . $date . '</div>';
            echo '</div>';
            echo '</div>';
            echo '</div>';
        }
    }
}
```

**update.php**

```
<?php


$writerId = filter_input(INPUT_GET,'Writer');

$returnCode = 0;

if(isset($writerId)){
    //Proceed to your update function

    //Assign a new returnCode
}

//We redirect to your main page

header("Location : path/to/your/previous/page/page.php?Code=$returnCode");
```